# Cordova Failing To Build

Tags: android, cordova

I am a front-end developer and I am working on a app for a tech company. Because I do primarily front-end html/css/js work I'm somewhat unfamiliar on what to do when cordova fails to build, though I usually get through it by searching, I cannot find a solution to my problem. Any help is appreciated!

When I tried to run the app I got a console error informing me I needed to install the ai.api.apiai plugin so I installed it via the command line and it is appearing in the config.xml file.

This is where my trouble began.

When I run this in command line:

```
cordova build
```

I get this error:

> :transformClassesWithDexForDebug FAILED
>
> BUILD FAILED
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
>
>   > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
>   >     java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.DexException:
>   >     Multiple dex files define
>   >     Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat;
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Total time: 15.9 secs (node:6184) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise
>     rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code
>     1 Error output: FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
>
>   > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
>   >     java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.DexException:
>   >     Multiple dex files define
>   >     Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat;
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. (node:6184) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In
>     the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the
>     Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Now I did try a couple of attempts such as adding to my gradle file this line of code:

```
defaultConfig{
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

**But this caused another error during the build so I got rid of this line of code.**

Answer (score 0):

Please add this dependency if not present, in `build.gradle` -> `compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'`

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. I'll need you to be very specific with this because I'm not familiar. I found a build.gradle file. I opened it and added that as a line of code. I received this: * What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
> Could not find method compile() for arguments [com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0] on root project 'android' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

Comment: UPDATE: I did research and put the code you provided under the dependencies in build.gradle file. That passed but I got this error during cordova build: FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat;

Comment: UPDATE 2: OK I re-added multiDexEnabled true and that solved the issue but another came in it's place, let me know if you also know how to solve this, thanks for getting me through that other one: What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/v4/graphics/BitmapCompat.class